# Standard SCPI commands - Hantek DSO4004C Series

Tags: oscilloscope, scpi

I own an oscilloscope from Hantek (DSO4254C). Want to write my own library for accessing the DSO in C which uses the [usbtmc](https://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/usbtmc.htm) driver in Linux. Are there some standard IEEE488 commands which the DSO supports? I can't find any information in the official SCPI manual from Hantek. Tried the standard `*IDN?` query first and it works as expected, but isn't documented in the [manual](http://www.hantek.com/down.aspx?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hantek.com%2FProduct%2FDSO4000BC%2FDSO4000BC_SCPI_EN.pdf).

Are there some other command/queries which are defined by the standard but not documented in the manual? I'm new with SCPI commands and the standard.

Comment: It has been a while since I last heard about these. From memory they use some weird protocol wrapper the forward any command other than idn?. They have some software to control it. And can capture what it sends in wireshark

Comment: They follow same between Manufacturers. this is the link i saw in web. http://www.hantek.com/down.aspx?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hantek.com%2fProduct%2fDSO4000BC%2fDSO4000BC_SCPI_EN.pdf

Comment: @user19579 I have already mentioned this link in my question.

Comment: @krjdev: I can't access that. It has all the commands supported on DSO. what you mean by "Are there some other command/queries which are defined by the standard but not documented in the manual?"

Comment: @user19579 Sorry, I didn't notice that. Was logged in on the site. I mean, are there some standard commands which all manufactures must implement and where they are documented by Hantek? Found this [specification](https://www.ivifoundation.org/docs/scpi-99.pdf).